# Value not assigning inside select tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am calling a javascript which is returning variable

```
options = '<option value="' + dateVal + '">' + dateText + '</option>' + '<option value="' + dateVal + '">' + dateText + '</option>';
```

Also my `select` element has an id="select-value"
and in javascript i am writting 
`document.getElementById("select-value").value=options;` but it is not taking any values nor throwing any error
I have also tried 
`document.getElementById("select-value").innerHTML=options;` but still no luck.

PFB my html code for `select`

```
<select name="select-name"  id="select-value" ></select>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   formatSelectedDate();
 </script>
```

Comment: what you are doing with your returned variable ??

Comment: Why does the code make the same options twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to use appendChild instead of innerHTML.

```
var s = document.getElementById("select-id");
var op1 = document.createElement("option");
op1.setAttribute("value",dateval);
s.appendChild(op1);
...
```

EDIT: it looks better inside a loop ;)